# BASH loop to change data from 1 csv from other csv

Tags: bash

trying to change the value of a column based on other column in other csv

so let's say we have a CSV_1 that states with over 1000 lines with 3 columns

```
shape   Color    size  
round      2      big  
triangle   1      small   
square     3      medium
```

then we have a CSV2 that has only 10 with the following information

```
color  
1 REd  
2 Blue  
3 Yellow  
etc
```

now i want to change the value in column color in CSV_1 with the name of the color of CSV2

so in other words .. something like

```
for (i=0; i<column.color(csv1); i++) { 
if color.csv1=1; then
subustite with color.csv2=1  }
```

so that loop iterates in all CSV1 Color column and changes the value with the values from CSV2

Comment: yes will do thanks!

Comment: You said **c**sv files, but I cannot see any commans here. Do you use spaces or tabs to delimit them?

Comment: true! sorry i should have specified that, the ',' is the separator in this case!

Comment: Not a problem. That's what I'd expect from a csv file. But you should adapt your file examples to actually use `,` as the separator.

Answer (score 2):

An explicit loop for this would be very slow in bash. Use a command that does the line-wise processing for you.

`sed 's/abc/xyz/'` searches `abc` in each line and replaces it by `xyz`. Use this to search and replace the numbers in your 2nd column by the names from your 2nd file. The `sed` command can be automatically generated from the 2nd file using another `sed` command:

The following script assumes a CSV file without spaces around the delimiting `,`.

```
sed -E "$(sed -E '1d;s#^([^,]*),(.*)#s/^([^,]*,)\1,/\\1\2,/#' 2.csv)" 1.csv
```

#### Interactive Example

```
$ cat 1.csv 
shape,Color,size
round,2,big
triangle,1,small
square,3,medium
$ cat 2.csv 
color
1,REd
2,Blue
3,Yellow
$ sed -E "$(sed -E '1d;s#^([^,]*),(.*)#s/^([^,]*,)\1,/\\1\2,/#' 2.csv)" 1.csv
shape,Color,size
round,Blue,big
triangle,REd,small
square,Yellow,medium
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! i'll have to look more into deep into this! this sort of sed definitions are also still hard to follow for me! thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach, with `mapfile` which is a bash4+ feature and some common utilities in linux/unix.

Assuming both files are delimited with a comma `,`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mapfile -t colors_csv2 < csv2.csv

head -n1 csv1.csv

while IFS=, read -r shape_csv1 color_csv1 size_csv1; do
  for color_csv2 in "${colors_csv2[@]:1}"; do
    if [[ $color_csv1 == ${color_csv2%,*} ]]; then
      printf '%s,%s,%s\n' "$shape_csv1" "${color_csv2#*,}" "$size_csv1"
    fi
  done
done < <(tail -n +2 csv1.csv)
```

Would be very slow on large set of data/files.

---

If `ed` is available acceptable, with the bash shell.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ed -s csv1.csv < <(
  printf '%s\n' '1d' $'g|.|s|,|/|\\\ns|^|,s/|\\\ns|$|/|' '$a' ',p' 'Q' . ,p |
  ed -s csv2.csv
)
```

Comment: Thanks! im still not able to complete follow as i think i should have call the columns more differently as per the above code im not sure which one is the color for csv1 or which is the color for csv 2 or it will be easier to rename them with the same name both :/
so i get that on line 1 map we define the colors as the column name for csv2 right? 
then shape color, is referring to column in csv1 right?
we set the loop, with colors referring again to csv2
then the loop runs and checks if color from csv1 its in csv2 and changes the color in csv1 am i right? . again thanks for your time! :)

Comment: I have change the variable names, hopefully it will give you an idea, add the debug flag `bash -x ./myscript` to see what is the script actually doing. Tested both on your sample files.

Comment: There are two loops, one `for` and the other a `while` loop with the `read` builtin.

Answer (score 1):

To add to [@Jetchisel interesting answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67853677/3641635), here is an old bash way to achieve that. It should work with bash release 2 as it supports escape literals, indexed array, string expansion,  indirect variable references. It implies that color keys in `csv2.csv` will always be a numeric value. Add `shopt -s compat31` at the beginning to test it in the 'old way' with a recent bash. You can also replace `declare -a csv2` with a Bash 4+ `declare -A csv2` for an associative array, in which case the key can be anything.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
declare -a csv2
esc=$'\x1B'
while read -r colors; do
   if [ "${colors}" ] ; then
     colors="${colors// /${esc}}"
     set ${colors//,/ }
     if [ "$1" ] ; then
       csv2["$1"]="$2"
     fi
   fi
done < csv2.csv
while read -r output; do
   if [ "${output}" ] ; then
     outputfilter="${output// /${esc}}"
     set ${outputfilter//,/ }
     if [ "$2" ] ; then
       color="${csv2["$2"]}"
       [ "${color}" ] && { tmp="$1,${color},$3";output="${tmp//${esc}/ }"; };
     fi
     echo "${output}"
   fi
done < csv1.csv
```

Comment: I have learned something new, well not new but tricks to use for old shells, I'll keep this bookmarked :-)